# reduce the size of a formula in an optimization problem

Tags: align

I need suggestions to reduce the length of the first line of the document below so that it doesn't exceed the size of the column:

[image]

Here is the script:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran_ICC}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}


\begin{align}
& P : \max_{\{a_i(c, \mathbf{z}) \, i \in \mathcal{N}_k \, c \in \mathcal{C}_k \, \mathbf{z} \in \mathcal{Z}_i^k, y_{ij} \, 1 \leq j \leq m \}} \sum_{k} \pi(\mathcal{N}_k) \sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}_k} U_i \left(\sum \nolimits^m_{j=1} l_j \cdot y_{ij}  \right) \nonumber \\
& \textrm{Subject to: } \nonumber \\
&\hspace{10mm} \textrm{constraint 1} \label{eq:rate_constraint} \\
&\hspace{10mm} \textrm{constraint 2} \label{eq:schedule_constraint} \\
&\hspace{10mm} \textrm{constraint 3} \label{eq:bitrate_constraint1} \\
\nonumber
\end{align}

\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
& P : \max_{\substack{\{a_i(c, \mathbf{z}) \, i \in \mathcal{N}_k \\ 
                        c \in \mathcal{C}_k, \,\mathbf{z} \in \mathcal{Z}_i^k, y_{ij} \\ 
                        1 \leq j \leq m \}}} 
        \sum_{k} \pi(\mathcal{N}_k) \sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}_k} U_i \biggl(\sum^m_{j=1} l_j\cdot y_{ij}\biggr) \nonumber \\
& \textrm{Subject to: } \nonumber \\
&\hspace{10mm} \textrm{constraint 1} \label{eq:rate_constraint} \\
&\hspace{10mm} \textrm{constraint 2} \label{eq:schedule_constraint} \\
&\hspace{10mm} \textrm{constraint 3} \label{eq:bitrate_constraint1} \\
\nonumber
\end{align}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You write in the last pair of parentheses `\bigl...\biggr`. Probably an oversight.

Comment: @MarianG., you are right. Corrected.Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarianG., usually `\left( .... \right)` is the simplest way out.